# Angular2 navigation and sub navigation nested routing

Tags: angular

I have a navigation menu and a sub navigation menu. You can see route config.

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
{
  path: "user",
  component: UserComponent,
  children: [
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
    { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent }
  ]
},
{
  path: "consultants",
  component: ConsultantsComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: "find-consultant",
      component: FindConsultantComponent
    },
    { path: "login-consultant", component: LoginConsultantComponent }
  ]
}
];
```

The navigation menu and the sub navigation menu are working and loading components. Here the scenario is when I clicked user->register, RegisterComponent is loaded. Later I clicked consultants->find-consultant, FindConsultantComponent is loaded. After turn back to `User` `RegisterComponent` not activated. I created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/navbar-routing

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. I have found an issue in **consultants.component.html** file. Please replace your code with below code then it will work fine.

**consultants.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-underline">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-target="#login" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                routerLink="/user/login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-bs-target="#register" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                routerLink="/user/register">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its same didnt change anything. When I click user link two components are loading again. I want to see activated sub nav menu.